# Change line color violon plolty graph object

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to erase/make transparent the line of each violin. In the photo, they are all in yellow (planning to define the color of each later) but I don't want the colored line round them.

```
events_name = ["Yellow card", "Red card", "2nd yellow -> Red card", "Goal", "Penalty", "substitution"]

fig = go.Figure()
for index, event in enumerate(events):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df_events['description'][df_events['description'] == event],
                            y=df_events['mn'][df_events['description'] == event],
                            name=events_name[index],
                            meanline_visible=True, 
                            bandwidth=0.9, fillcolor="yellow"))


fig.update_layout(title=f"Distribution of events over 90 minutes - ")
fig.update_xaxes(
        title_text = "Event", 
tickvals=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
ticktext=events_name)

fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text = "Minutes of the game",
        tickvals=list(range(0, 105, 15)))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have simulated you data to make this a repeatable example
- simply set **line_color** to plot background color

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

events_name = ["Yellow card", "Red card", "2nd yellow -> Red card", "Goal", "Penalty", "substitution"]
events = events_name
df_events = pd.DataFrame({"description":np.random.choice(events, 200), "mn":np.random.uniform(200)})

fig = go.Figure()
for index, event in enumerate(events):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df_events['description'][df_events['description'] == event],
                            y=df_events['mn'][df_events['description'] == event],
                            name=events_name[index],
                            meanline_visible=True, 
                            line_color=fig.layout["template"]["layout"]["plot_bgcolor"],
                            bandwidth=0.9, fillcolor="yellow"))


fig.update_layout(title=f"Distribution of events over 90 minutes - ")
fig.update_xaxes(
        title_text = "Event", 
tickvals=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
ticktext=events_name)

fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text = "Minutes of the game",
        tickvals=list(range(0, 105, 15)))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Do you know why some arguments are suggested when writing a function and why others are not? The doc doesn't mention it. https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Violin.html

Comment: plotly is a large API and has many permutations. Documentation becomes too big if every use case permutation is called out.  your case is called out https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.violin.html#plotly.graph_objects.violin.Line